# how to invoke script after receipt of mail automatically?

Tags: perl, email, qmail

I am developing one application where I need to invoke a Perl script as soon as mail receives. I am using QMAIL as MTA. I read about Qmail-qfilter where we can intercept inbound mail but I am using Qmail 1.06 where Qmail-qfilter is not inbuilt package. I tried to search that package but it's outdated, So I am not getting proper solution for it.

So, I want to know where I need to mention automatic execution of Perl script as soon as my mail receives in qmail and what is alternative way for Qmail-qfilter.

Comment: Do want to process incoming mails to all local mailboxes to a few a few "per OS account" mailboxes?

Comment: Want to process incoming mails to all mailboxes

Answer (score 1):

If you are really sure about executing one perl process per incoming mail, you might call it from a .qmail file as a delivery pipeline. The [man page to dot-qmail](http://www.qmail.org/man/man5/dot-qmail.html) has details.